# Prefent Resubmission in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, form-submit

im newbie and i want to ask you about this matter, anyone know what should i do if i want to prefent resubmission ? So when the user click back button on their browser it redirect to warning page resubmission ? cause in my case if user click back he back to form that is filled and can click submit again

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the link you provided. On the link, it's about people "REFRESHING" the page and seeing a box asking them to confirm resubmission. This user is more concerned about going in the process and begin able to resubmit the same form with previous data. And he's got a point in terms of security. You don't want someone to be able to navigate back on your browser and see all your information you filled in a form.

Comment: hello @EddyTheDove nice to see you again.. yup its not what im searching for T_T